# About factorization with respect to tensor product.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, tensor-products, quadratic-programming

So I was trying to factorize some tensor $w_{mn}$ into $v_m \otimes u_n$.
But such factorization does not always exist. Therefore I turned into an estimate problem:
**Given complex valued $A_{m\times n}$, how can we find $u_{m\times 1}, v_{n\times 1}$ that minimize $\|A-u\otimes v\| = \|A-u^Tv\|$?**
In which the norm chosen can be arbitrary, for example, l2 norm (square variance).

What I really need is some sort of numerical algorithm that is efficient enough. But I just cannot think of any easy way to solve it.

Comment: Probably, the only deterministic algorithm is using singular value decomposition, setting all but biggest singular values to zero and multiplying back, so you should look for best SVD implementation.

Comment: Oh, but how do you ensure that it is a good approximation?
Regarding which norm?